# Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda>0$

Tags: statistics

I am currently studying Poisson distribution.

I could understand
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}(X) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k \lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}= \\
&= e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k+1}}{k!}=\\
&= \lambda
\end{align}
but $\text{E}(X(X-1)) = \lambda^2$ why is this true ?

How can I check it ? I have no idea to check $E(X-1)$ and $E(X(X-1))$ instead of just $X$.

Comment: To the op. You can use LaTeX notation in the postings here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that if $X$ is a random variable taking integers values, and $f$ is a "not too bad behaved" function, we have 
$$\mathbb E[\color{red}{f}(X)]=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\color{red}{f(k)}\mathbb P(X=k).$$
So you have to use this formula with $f(k):=k-1$, then with $f(k)=k(k-1)$. For the latter, we use the same "trick": the first two terms vanish, then we simplify the factorial and we change the index of summation.

Comment: thank you but could you explain with some examples please ? I am really struggling to understand that.

Comment: Example: $P(X=k)=2^{-k}, k\geq 1$. Then $E[X]=\sum_{k\geq 1}k2^{—k}$, $E[X^p]=\sum_{k\geq 1}k^p2^{-k}$.

Comment: hmmm .....still confused

Answer (score 0):

If one is aware that $E(X)=Var(X)=\lambda$ where $X\sim Po(\lambda)$, then why not use the fact that $E(X^2) = Var(Y) + E(Y)^2$?

Then
$$E(X(X-1)) = E(X^2) - E(X) = \lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda = \lambda^2.$$